# How to wrap into act(...) second/deferred/async rendering

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component:

```
function MyComp(props) {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => { loadItems(); }, []);

    async function loadItems() {
        const result = await axios.get(`https://example.com/api`);
        setItems(result.data);
    }

    return (<div>{items.map(item => ...)}</div>);
}
```

And this test produces the act warning:

```
const items = { "data": [{"id": 1, "title": "Title1"}] };
axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(items)); 
const wrapper = mount(<MyComp />);
```

> Warning: An update to MyComp inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

From what I understand this happens because of the second update with fetched items. How to solve this issue?

EDIT: This helped

```
let wrapper = null;
await act(async () => {
    wrapper = mount(<MyComp />);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try?

```
    import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

//...
    
        let wrapper = null;
        act(() => {
          wrapper = mount(<MyComp />);
        });
```

EDIT: here you can find more info https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act

Comment: Thank you, in my case, I also needed *async* and *await*.

Answer (score 1):

The promise needs to be awaited before asserting the result. It can be obtained either by storing a reference to `Promise.resolve(items)` or getting it from a spy:

```
...
const wrapper = mount(<MyComp />);
expect(axios.get).toBeCalledTimes(1);
await axios.get.mock.results[0];
// assert the result
```

Comment: This is a good point, but it doesn't solve the problem with `act(...)` warning. May this warning come from the fact that setting the state is delayed?