# Jest - Unit test failing for asynchronous operation

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a **Users** component with the usersData that I am getting from the server shown below,

```
export const Users: FunctionComponent<any> = () => {
    const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState<TableConfig>();
    let initialLoad = false;
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!usersData) {
            fetchMockUsers().then((result: any) => {
                initialLoad = true;
                setUsersData(result);
            });
        }
    }, [usersData]);
    const handlePageSelection = useCallback((offset, pageSize) => {
        if (!initialLoad) {
            fetchMockUsers(offset, pageSize).then((result: any) => {
                setUsersData(result);
            });
        }
        initialLoad = false;
    }, []);
    return (usersData &&
        <TableWithPagination id="securityUsers" className="user-listing"
           paginationConfig={{ totalItems: 16, handlePageSelection: handlePageSelection }} tableData={usersData} />)
        || <Loader />;
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test for this component. For that, I mocked the fetch call initially and resolved it with some dummy data. What is happening here is, the line is covering inside the **useEffect** but **TableWithPagination** is not available in the DOM as it is showing up based on the API response.

**test file**

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import {Users} from './usersAndUserGroups';

jest.mock('../../../services/common/userService',
    () => ({
        fetchMockUsers: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
            headerFields: { key: "userName", value: "User Name", sortable: false },
            rowDataList: [{ userName: "Adriana Ocampo" }]
        })
    }));

describe('Users and User group Listing Component', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Users />);

    it('should render in the DOM', () => {
        console.log('WRAPPER', wrapper.debug());

        const container = wrapper.find('.user-listing');

        expect(container.length).toEqual(1); // failing
    });

    
    it('should render in the DOM', () => {
        const container = wrapper.find('TableWithPagination');

        expect(container.length).toEqual(1); // Failed because  TableWithPagination is present in the DOM 
        // ERROR - expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    });



});
```

Getting this error while running the unit test:-

```
● Users and User group Listing Component › should render in the DOM

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: 0

      21 |              const container = wrapper.find('.user-listing');
      22 |
    > 23 |              expect(container.length).toEqual(1);
         |                                       ^
      24 |      });
      25 |
      26 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/admin-app/components/security/users-and-groups/usersAndUserGroups.test.js:23:28)

  ● Users and User group Listing Component › should render in the DOM

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: 0

      28 |              const container = wrapper.find('TableWithPagination');
      29 |
    > 30 |              expect(container.length).toEqual(1); // Failed because  TableWithPagination is present in the DOM
         |                                       ^
      31 |              // ERROR - expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
      32 |      });
      33 |


console.log src/admin-app/components/security/users-and-groups/usersAndUserGroups.test.js:18
    WRAPPER <Users>
      <Loader>
        <div className="d-r35-loader">
          <div className="d-r35-loader__spinner">
            <div className="sk-fading-circle">
              <div className="sk-circle1 sk-circle" />
              <div className="sk-circle2 sk-circle" />
              <div className="sk-circle3 sk-circle" />
              <div className="sk-circle4 sk-circle" />
              <div className="sk-circle5 sk-circle" />
              <div className="sk-circle6 sk-circle" />
              <div className="sk-circle7 sk-circle" />
              <div className="sk-circle8 sk-circle" />
              <div className="sk-circle9 sk-circle" />
              <div className="sk-circle10 sk-circle" />
              <div className="sk-circle11 sk-circle" />
              <div className="sk-circle12 sk-circle" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="d-r35-loader__message">
            Loading...
          </div>
        </div>
      </Loader>
    </Users>

  console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:88
    Warning: An update to Users inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
```

Here you can see the wrapper is not updated with the API response. still, it is showing the LOADER

Please point out if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the above issue,

```
 describe('Users and User group Listing Component', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<Users />);
    
        
        it('should render in the DOM', () => {
            wrapper.update(); // this will update the dom with the server data
            const container = wrapper.find('TableWithPagination');
    
            expect(container.length).toEqual(1); // started working
        });
    
    
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64197030/3731501), the promise that `fetchMockUsers` returns needs to be awaited before the result can be asserted. The promise can be retrieved from `fetchMockUsers` spy:

```
const wrapper = mount(<Users />);

expect(fetchMockUsers).toBeCalledTimes(1);
await fetchMockUsers.mock.results[0];

const container = wrapper.find(TableWithPagination);
expect(container.length).toEqual(1)
```

Components cannot be reliably identified by names, `find` should be used with `TableWithPagination` component rather than a string.

Comment: How will I access fetchMockUsers from the jest.mock ?

Comment: Import it the same way as you did in a place where you used it.